# If the Earth is moving, then how is it possible to slow down light?

Tags: visible-light, reference-frames, speed-of-light, relativity, earth

Given the following:

1. Earth is spinning on its axis and also rotating around the sun.
2. Light has no mass and is not affected by our moving atmosphere

When we slow down light as is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EK6HxdUQm5s) to a mere 38 miles-per-hr, then shouldnt the light move away from us at vast speeds?

I understand that light is affected by the earth. But is it affected in such a way that where-ever the earth moves, the light also moves in perfect step with the earth as to give the impression that the earth is stationary?

Any links to guide me in the right direction is much appreciated. This question is in relation to future computers using light pulses to operate.

**Therefore Question:**
**Why doesnt the slowed down light fly out of the medium considering that the earth is moving, but the light is almost at a stand still?**

**[Edit]** This question was put on hold because it says it is unclear what I am asking. I do not know how else to phrase the question other than what is bolded above.  --> **Are there any reasons why the slowed down light does not fly out of the medium considering that the earth is moving, but the light is almost at a stand still**   Maybe someone can help me edit this?

Comment: Your impression that the Earth is stationary is mostly due to the fact that you are standing on it. It has nothing to do with light apart from the fact that, if there wasn't any light, then you would not be able to see where you were standing.

Answer (score 2):

So the universe doesn't have a fixed background frame of reference that you can use to determine how absolutely fast most things are going. relativity makes this a little bit more complicated, because anything moving at the speed of light in vacuum does have the same speed when various people look at it, no matter how they move relative to each other, but that is somewhat of a subtle point. Anything moving slower than that, you have to ask what the speed is being measured relative to.

In this case, they are slowing down light relative to a strange state of matter known as a Bose-Einstein condensate.but the important point is, this is just a lump of stuff, that exists in some experimental apparatus, which keeps it cold and keeps it in one place for measurements, relative to that apparatus.

The experiment would be significantly more costly if we put it on a supersonic jet so that it could oppose Earth's rotation and be at a fixed point relative to Earth's axis of rotation. But it is very unlikely that we would see any new physics as a result of that, because there is no absolute frame of reference, and you could just as easily ask why we're not canceling out the motion of the earth about the sun, or the motion of the sun about the center of the milky way galaxy, or the motion of any of this stuff relative to the cosmic microwave background radiation. And you can only choose one of those to slow light down relative to.

Since the accomplishment is the same no matter what spaceship you put it in, Earth is just as good a spaceship as any other.

Comment: Hmm. confused on one thing. Why does the experiment need to take place on a supersonic jet which opposes earth's rotation? The same can be accomplished on the ground as in the original experiment. A laser beam flying through the air inside the condensate close to the ground and will be the same as a laser beam flying through the air in a condensate at the altitude of an airplane. ..?

Answer (score 1):

The answer about no universal frame of reference seems closest to me, but keep in mind, relativity of the constant speed of light is in a vacuum only. As mentioned, an Einstein-Bose condensate will slow down light, but so will glass, water, and even air (though much less dramatically). What matters here I think are two things.

1. The medium is not a vacuum and so it does not travel at c. Were it to travel in a vacuum then it would be traveling away from the earth at c, but only because all things are  essentially traveling at the same speed through space-time.
2. All things travel at a constant speed through space time. The faster the “speed” through space, the slower the “speed” through time. There is no fixed frame of reference for space and time so this can get tricky to conceptualize, but from the perspective of the patch of earth you are standing on and yourself, you are both moving at essentially the same speed through space and time relative to each other. Slowing light in this medium does the same, and there is a corresponding affect on time for the light (I believe time is sped up for the photons relative to you and your patch of earth, but can’t cite a source there, so could be wrong). This all changes drastically if we compare this to an asteroid catapulted at 20% of c away from the earth. Suddenly the reference for time and space have changed for you and the asteroid, so the light in a vacuum would be moving away from you at c and toward it at c even though it is moving away from you at 20%. It wouldn’t be c + 20% c for you even though it is absolutely true that the light is moving toward the asteroid at c. This is because the reference for time will also be different relative to you and relative to the asteroid.

So what I’m trying to say here is that the speed of light is affected by the material (or lack thereof in vacuum), but so is the reference for time, all of which is relative to whom the observer or the reference point is.

This is my understanding at least. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Light only has a constant velocity when traveling through a vacuum. When light travels through matter such as glass, or water, it does have a slower velocity than light in a vacuum. The different is in fact a measure of the [refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index).

The interesting thing about using a Bose-Einstein condensate, in the link you provided, was that the speed of light traveling through the condensate was slowed to a near stop.

Comment: i have updated the question in bold above. I do not think my original question was clear

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute frame of reference for velocity. When you state a velocity, it's always relative to some frame of reference.

The slow light is moving at 38 MPH relative to the chunk of Bose-Einstein condensate it's traveling through. And the chunk of Bose-Einstein condensate is at rest relative to the lab it's sitting in, and the lab is at rest relative to the Earth. The facts that the Earth is rotating around its axis and revolving around the Sun, the solar system is orbiting through the galaxy, etc, are irrelevant.

When light travels through a vacuum, all observers will measure its speed to be *c* (299792458 metres per second), no matter which frame of reference they're using. That's the basis of Einstein's theory of Special Relativity, and it's a bit hard to get your head around, at first. But we don't need to worry about that stuff here, because the light traveling through the Bose-Einstein condensate is moving so slowly.

Answer (score 0):

A photon explanation:

Real photons always travel at velocity c, due to special relativity rules.   Light is a quantum mechanical superposition of photons, not simple, it is explainable with quantum electrodynamics, as discussed [here for example](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html).

[In this link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402616309603) the model used for photons in a medium assumes that they  become massive.

In the video one can observe the slowed down pulse, so it means real photons scatter off  the medium's atoms and get out of the pulse and reach our eye.

This is not my field, but the mathematical solution that comes to mind is that the bulk of the red pulse consists of [virtual photons(](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)unseen), the real ones having transferred their energy to the medium.  Virtual photons do not have the energy momentum constraint, they can have a mass larger than zero and thus mathematically be slowed down.  When the edge of the medium is reached they become real zero mass photons. The red color seen as the traveling pulse, is photons shed from the virtual pulse by scattering on the atoms of the medium.

Thus it is virtual electromagnetic waves that form an energy-momentum  pulse, their energy and momentum stored in the Bose Einstein condensate in a complicated quantum mechanical way as virtual photons. A few of them interface with the atoms, scattering and becoming real, so the pulse can be seen to move, until the end of the medium is reached and the photons become on shell again.

> Therefore Question: Why doesnt the slowed down light fly out of the medium considering that the earth is moving, but the light is almost at a stand still?

As I explained above in the quantum mechanical model with photons, the pulse seen is just an energy momentum pulse on the Bose Ensteing Condensate, not an electromagnetic wave. As it is propagating on the structure of the medium, there is nothing that can fly out. Take a simple sound pulse on a medium, the medium moves with the motion of the earth and the sound pulse is in the medium.

Answer (score 0):

It is effected by the Earth, but only as a type of frame dragging effect on light. The Lense-Thirring effect shows that the direction light takes in respect to the rotation of a planet like earth, is significant, that the photon has more length to pass through when moving against the rotation of Earth.

This is the effect of a gravitational distortion, not so much different to the Shapiro effect. In a way, the rotation of Earth is dragging spacetime in the direction of its spin and in doing so, we have a very weak torsion like effect on spacetime, meaning the photon has to travel a little bit further.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore Question: Why doesnt the slowed down light fly out of the
>   medium considering that the earth is moving, but the light is almost
>   at a stand still?

The light is not at a standstill.

If you drop a stone in water it will create waves, and you'll note they travel at, say 1m/s. But if you had a super-microscope that could see the molecules in the water, you'd notice they are all travelling at around 1,500 m/s. If you don't recognize it, that's the speed of sound in water.

So if the water molecules are moving at 1,500 m/s, how is the wave moving at 1? That's because, and this is the key issue, **a water wave is not a physical object.** It is the **collective behaviour of many objects**, in this case the water molecules. When you drop the stone in the water it hits some of those molecules, so they're not going 1500 but 1501, and then they bump the one beside it and make it go 1501 while they slow back to 1500, and that new one bumps another... so the **net motion** is a wave 1 m/s. It's actually more complex than that, but you get the idea.

So back to your example. You are not looking at the light, you are looking at the **light wave**. Yes, there's a difference. With an even better super-microscope you could look inside and see the photons, the "real light" so to speak, going the speed of light. Light always goes the speed of light, whether it's inside a crystal or a B-E, or in space, or near the Earth.

What's happening is that any one photon is being repeatedly absorbed and re-emitted, and spends a lot of time "not existing" except as energy inside the atoms of of the material. So while the photons inside the material are still going c, the "overall effect", the wave itself, is going 38 mph. Again, it's more complex than what I've written here, but you get the idea.

Another example: it takes light hundreds of years to get out of the sun. Now if you measure the sun, it's not that big, it should take about two seconds. What's happening in this case is that the sun is so fantastically dense that the photon can't move very far before hitting something. The photons are bouncing around constantly, being absorbed and re-emitted, splitting into parts in various reactions, and so forth.

The motion of the Earth has no effect one way or the other.